# Ускорить\оптимизировать SELECT WHERE IN SELECT

Tags: mysql

Есть две разных таблицы, необходимо из первой выбрать только те записи, поле из которых существует во второй

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field1 in (SELECT field FROM table2)

В первой таблице 10 миллионов записей, во второй - 500 тысяч.
Выполняется такой запрос нереально долго и честно говоря, я даже не рискнул дождаться завершения.

Может можно как-то оптимизировать?

Comment: Используйте `LIMIT` в подзапросе.

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, да понятно про лимит, но выборка нужна целиком, разве ж это как-то ускорит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field2
```

Ну и, само собой, наличие необходимых индексов (по полям связи, либо составных, где эти поля являются префиксом).